# python code meaning explanation

Tags: python, networkx

I have this python code. Can someone tell me what the conditions 'nodedef' and 'edgedef' stand for, what rule need to be satisfied that the condition is true.

I tryed to google the answer, but I didn't find anything usefull. I'm new to python so forgive me for my ignorance.

```
import numpy
import pandas
import networkx as nx
import unicodecsv as csv

path="comics-network.csv"

graph = nx.Graph(name="Characters in Comics")
with open(path, 'rb') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    for row in reader:
        if 'nodedef' in row[0]:
            handler = lambda row,G: G.add_node(row[0],TYPE=row[1])
        elif 'edgedef' in row[0]:
            handler = lambda row,G: G.add_edge(*row)
        else:
            handler=(row, graph)
```

Comment: They're strings.  It looks like whatever file you're reading from will have them in the text.

Comment: You are loading a .csv file; for each row, if the first item is "nodedef" treat it as a node, else if it is "edgedef" treat it as an edge, otherwise ?? I am not sure what the last bit is doing. There should be a bit more code, showing what happens to `handler` once it is created.

Comment: What does the file look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to guess, commenting line by line:

```
    # for each row in the CSV
    for row in reader:
        # if the first column of the row contains the string 'nodedef' 
        if 'nodedef' in row[0]:
            # make the name "handler" point to this function (node?)
            handler = lambda row,G: G.add_node(row[0],TYPE=row[1])
        # else, check if it contains the string 'edgedef' 
        elif 'edgedef' in row[0]:
            # make the name "handler" point to this function instead (edge?)
            handler = lambda row,G: G.add_edge(*row)
        else:
            # make the name "handler" point to this tuple (root?)
            handler=(row, graph)
```

I presume it is doing something with "handler" afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is the beginning of some code that constructs an in-memory representation of a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)) based on a human readable representation of a graph (e.g. [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list)).

I suspect that your CSV uses the strings 'nodedef' to state that the following data on the line refers to a node in the graph, and 'edgedef' to state that the following data refers to an edge on the graph.